# How to update the content in select2 dropdown menu after ajax success function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the below code to update the content in select2 dropdown menu after ajax success function

```
  $.ajax(
{
url:'test.php',
type: 'POST',
data:'start='+start,
success:function(e)
{
var response=e; 
$('#field-video-keywords #optkeywords option:last').after(response);
$("#field-video-keywords").select2('close');                                                        
  $("#field-video-keywords").select2('open');   


},
error: function()
{
alert('Error');                     
}
});
```

Content is updating,but  the update is visible while the dropdown is closing and then opening..Please help me to fix the issue

**Update**
THanks for the valuable responses,
I was able to append the response data. but while i scroll down the list, it goes back to the top of the selection list. How can i overcome this issue

```
    $('#keywords ul.select2-results').scroll(function()
{
var div = $(this);
var keywordscount=$('#keywordscount').text();
var newkeywordscount = Number(keywordscount) + Number(20);
if (div[0].scrollHeight - div.scrollTop() == div.height())
{
$.ajax(
{
url:'test.php',
type: 'POST',
data:'start='+newkeywordscount,
success:function(e)
{                           
var response=e; 
$("#field-video-keywords").select2('close');
$('#field-video-keywords #optkeywords option:last').after(response);
$("#field-video-keywords").select2('open'); 
$('#keywordscount').html(newkeywordscount);
},
error: function()
{
alert('Error');                     
}
});
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the success function to this:

```
success:function(e) {
    var response=e; 
    $("#field-video-keywords").select2('destroy');  
    $('#field-video-keywords option:last').after(response);                                                              
    $("#field-video-keywords").select2('');   
},
```

This should re-create the select2 with your new item.